# What is the size of the face-centered orthogonal projection of a regular dodecahedron?

Tags: geometry, polyhedra, projection

What is the edge length of the regular decagon that is the external boundary of the face-centered orthogonal projection of a regular dodecahedron of edge length 1?

In other words, in this diagram of a regular dodecahedron:
[image]
If the edge length of the pentagons in the middle are 1, then what is the edge length of the decagon on the outside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see that the outer vertices belong to both a pentagon of edge $\phi$, and a decagon.  Since the pentagon edge is the shortchord of the decagon, we can derive the edge direct as

$\frac{\phi}{\sqrt{\phi\sqrt{5}}}$, or $\sqrt{\frac{\phi}{\sqrt 5}}$.

Putting in values, we get 1.61803398875/1.90211303259.

Comment: Right.  If you put every other outer vertex in a plane you can project face-centered into that plane.  Diagonals of pentagons with edge 1 have length $\phi$.  Thanks, Wendy!

Comment: Great!  A cleaner simplification of the value is $ \sqrt{\frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{10}} $, for any future readers of this question.

Comment: The first value is a(5)/a(10), where a(x) is the shortchord of polygon x.  This is what the values represent.  The rest is algebra that goes away from the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The [Cartesian coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_dodecahedron#Cartesian_coordinates) of the vertices of one regular dodecahedron with edge length $\sqrt 5-1$ are $(\pm 1, \pm 1, \pm 1), (0, \pm \phi, \pm \phi^{-1}), (\pm  \phi^{-1}, 0, \pm \phi),(\pm \phi, \pm \phi^{-1}, 0),$ with $\phi$ being the Golden Ratio: $\phi = \frac {1+\sqrt 5}{2}$.  So scale the edge length back to 1, drop the last coordinate and get distances between outer vertices.

Comment: I considered that approach, but unfortunately it gets you the values for the edge-centered orthogonal projection, not the face-centered orthogonal projection.  Some rotation is needed before the last coordinate can be dropped -- and I got lost trying to figure out how to do that...

Comment: Yeah... I just noticed that myself.

Comment: This really should have nice answer, without needing much more than basic geometry... still thinking.

Comment: You can literally see the infinitely many parallel lines in the <a href=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model#/media/File:Poincare_disc_hyperbolic_parallel_lines.svg">Poincare disk model</a>